# FileHelpers not influence on data

Tags: .net, filehelpers

When i define comma as file separator for new file i just noticed that when i placed comma within data this comma will be placed in the output file, so does it mean that FileHelpers is not influence on data itself automaticly or? For instance also for quotes or whatever as i thought FileHelpers contains already inner engines to "correct" such things automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

You must add [FieldQuoted] to make the library auto use quotes when the fields contains the delimiter

http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_FieldQuotedAttribute.htm

Also check the QuoteMode parameter

http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_QuoteMode.htm

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Records
{
   // It will always contains " on output and require it for read
   [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
   public string Name;

   // It will add " if the data cantains a , and will read with no quotes
   [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
   public string Track;

   [FieldQuoted]
   public string worldPrice;
}
```

Comment: @MarcosMeil Please answer me to this 1st Q:as i see if i use QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted - then whatever is within data e.g double quotes, commas will stay as it is but all data will be surrounded by "" right? 2nd Q: if i use QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth and there will be commas and quotes inside then all stay as it is but all data will be surrounded by quotes, BUT if there are no additional commas within data but only additional quotes all data will be surrounded BUT additional quotes will be reduced to every "" --> " can you explain?

Comment: @JimmyJimm Exactly AlwaysQuoted always add the " to the output. OptionalForWrite and OptiminalForBoth will add the " if the data contains a NewLine (in MultilineMode) or a Delimiter (in your case ,) if online contains a " with no commas so the library don't escape it because the unique problem is the delimiter

Comment: i noticed only without any QuoteMode defined it will stay data as it is right?   Can you also explain why OptiminalForBoth and OptionalForWrite are duplicationg double quotes within data for instance this string: ddd""ddd""hhh will be outputed like this: "ddd""""ddd""""hhh" so not only surround by double quotes but also duplicating additional quotes inside.

Comment: P.S I do not see any diffrence between OptiminalForBoth, OptiminalForRead, OptiminalForWrite - as i see during test all is the same using one of three.

Comment: @JimmyJimm The double quotes escape is what the csv do to avoid that the field ends there

Comment: so does it mean that for each additional double quote it will make additional one? And what is diffrence between those tree i mentioned as i see no diffrence in action?